# discord js collector - mensagens de paginação não funcionam

Tags: javascript, node.js

Esses dias estou aprendendo um pouco sobre desenvolvimento de bots, e no processo pesquisei sobre mensagens de paginação e acabei encontrando o `discord.js` `collector`.

No site havia alguns exemplos prontos, então usei um deles no `Repl.it` e funcionou normalmente. Depois disso mudei para o VSCode e, ao executar o comando ele mostrou o seguinte erro:

> (node:7688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
> at Function.keys ()
> at Function.__createReactionCollector (D:\Users\MYPC\Desktop\BotTest\node_modules\discord.js-collector\src\collectors\reactionCollector.js:405:34)
> at Function.paginator (D:\Users\MYPC\Desktop\BotTest\node_modules\discord.js-collector\src\collectors\reactionCollector.js:329:32)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> (node:7688) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
> (node:7688) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

O problema do código é que não aparecem os emojis para mudar de página. De começo achei que precisaria configurar os emojis no código, contudo, no exemplo não havia nada do tipo.

Já dei uma olhada na pasta do package para saber se tinha alguma coisa que me ajudasse, mas os exemplos são os mesmos ou levam para o github.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

O código é este:

```
const { ReactionCollector } = require ('discord.js-collector');
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client()
client.on("Pronto?", () => {
    console.log("Pronto!");
});
exports.run = async (_, message) => {
      const botMessage = await message.reply('Testeteste');

        ReactionCollector.paginator({
        botMessage,
        user: message.author,
        pages: [
          new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('')
            .setDescription('') 
            .setImage('')
            .setFooter('')
            .setURL(''),
          new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('')
            .setDescription('') 
            .setImage('')
            .setFooter('')
            .setURL('')
        ],
            collectorOptions: {
              time: 350000
                    

        }
            
    });
}
```

As embeds não estão vazias, só coloquei assim para o código não ficar enorme.

Answer (score 0):

Passando para dizer que já consegui resolver o meu problema. O que fiz foi utilizar a mesma versão do `node.js` do `repl.it`.